# Persist data after app killing in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am building an online shop app using Flutter, and I am wondering what is the best way to persist data after the user exit the app or when the app is killed. The data I want to persist is the cart information, which contains a complex structure.
It worth mentioning that I'm using Provider for state management.

I was thinking of the below approaches:

1. Creating a local file and read/write info from/to it.
2. Shared preferences
3. The new Flutter feature with RestorationMixin, (I don't know how to deal with a complex structure in addition to using Provider).

Comment: Have you thought of using shared_preferences? You can save an entire JSON in a String and convert it into an Object when you start the app. https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation .. I will try this

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreference`is the possible solution for you.

you can convert your `object` into `json` String by using `jsonEncode(object)` and save it in the `sharedpreference` and when you need back the `object` from `json string` you can use `jsonDecode(string)` to get your object back.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation .. I will try this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the data offline. I'd suggest using [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite). SQFlite is an sql database that will be saved locally on the device. It's easy to use and is persistant as you requested.

If you want to save data online in the cloud somewhere then I'd advice looking into Firebase (Google database, works really well with providers) or mongodart (MongoDB database)