# How can I persist and rehydrate multiprovider?

Tags: flutter, provider, persist

I want somehow save state of providers from Provider pub, just like **persistCombineReducers** from redux-persist as react-native analog.
I've tried this [Persist data after app killing in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65569606/persist-data-after-app-killing-in-flutter),
tried with hydrated package,
can't figure out how do this properly, thanks